# Vimでユーザー定義マクロの省略表記をハイライト表示するには？

Tags: c++, c, vim

まず初めに、プログラミング始めたての初心者なので筋違いの質問であるかもしれませんがすみません

c++などの言語でtypedefやusingを使って型名の省略とかをするとおもうのですが、その型名の省略先にも色をつけることは可能でしょうか？また、可能でなければそれを可能にするプラグインなどはありますか？例えば、

```
using ll = long long
```

としたとき、`long long`の方には色が付きますが、`ll`はテキストの色と同じ色のままなので、色をつけて目立たせたいです

Answer (score 2):

- 開いているファイル解析して、typedef や using を使っているところから自動で強調させるようにしたいのか?
- 単に*.c のファイルで、ll などをキーワードとして追加したいのか?

が解りませんが、後者なら比較的簡単そうです

[vimで構文のハイライトを自作する](https://qiita.com/kimurap/items/7058c9fe29f51932b196)
が参考になりそうです

そちらの環境が不明なので、具体性に書けますが、私の環境 (Ubuntu) だと *.c のファイルで
:syntax
で調べてみたら、型名は「cType」となっていたので、
~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim
に

```
syntax keyword cType ll
```

としてやると ll が型名として色が付きました